# Problemas para enviar con Whatsaap imagen con texto usando Selenium Python

Tags: python, imagen, selenium

después de la caída de WathsApp no puedo enviar un mensaje automático que contenga imagen y texto (texto solo, sí envía) entonces creería que algo en la sintaxis de envío del clip ha cambiado.
Acá la parte del código en donde creo que está fallando:
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//span[@data-testid="clip"]').click()

Les dejo todo el código por si es que alguno puede ayudarme con ello:

---

`#Extracto del código  driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/") sleep(40) #Busca el grupo a enviar el mensaje, "Grupo_Wsp_prueba" driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@title="Cuadro de texto para ingresar la búsqueda"]').send_keys('Grupo_Wsp_prueba') sleep(10) driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//span[@title="Grupo_Wsp_prueba"]').click() sleep(10)`

```
    #Selecciona la imagen 
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//span[@data-testid="clip"]').click()
    sleep(8)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@type="file"]').send_keys(RutaImagen1)
    sleep(8)

    text_area = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@title="Escribe un mensaje"]')
    string = "Texto texto texto texto"
    for part in string.split('\n'):
        text_area.send_keys(part)
        text_area.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.ENTER)

    sleep(20)
    #Enviar el mensaje
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@aria-label="Enviar"]').click()
    sleep(30)
```

Answer (score 1):

ya pude dar con la solución, con esta última actualización del wsp el ícono de envío de media files cambió. Les dejo la información por si es que a alguien le sirve:

> **Anterior:** driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//span[@data-testid="clip"]').click()
>
> **Actual:** driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//span[@data-testid="attach-menu-plus"]').click()

Espero les sirva.